# Determine if R is an equivalence relation on set A. A=RxR. (a,b) R (c,d) iff a=c or b=d.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, equivalence-relations

Determine if R is an equivalence relation on set A. A = RxR. (a,b) R (c,d) iff a=c or b=d.

Reflexive- Let (a,b) be in A. (a,b) R (a,b). Therefore, a=a or b=b.

R is not an equivalence relation on set A.

---

Is the above correct?

This question was on my test. Initially, I said "R is an equivalence relation on set A" and it was marked wrong.

Also, in my test I wrote, 
Transitive- Assume (a,b)R(c,d) and (c,d)R(e,f). 
So, a=c or b=d and c=e or d=f. 
Therefore, a=c=e and b=d=f. 
So (a,b)R(e,f). 
R is transitive.

Comment: The answer depends on $A$.

Comment: More specifically, $R$ is an equivalence relation if $A$ has at most one element, but it is not transitive if $A$ has at least two elements. If $a$ and $a'$ are distinct elements of $A$, then $$\langle a,a\rangle\mathrel{R}\langle a,a'\rangle \mathrel{R}\langle a',a'\rangle\;,$$ but $\langle a,a\rangle\not\mathrel{R}\langle a',a'\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you, yes if A has at most one element. Hence, the relation is reflexive and symmetric only. Makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

The relation is reflexive and symmetric, but not transitive.

For example, $(1,2)R(1,3)$ and $(1,3)R(0,3)$, but we do not have $(1,2) R (0,3)$.

Comment: Oh... in my test I wrote,
Transitive- Assume (a,b)R(c,d) and (c,d)R(e,f).
So, a=c or b=d and c=e or d=f.
Therefore, a=c=e and b=d=f.
So (a,b)R(e,f).
R is transitive.

Comment: (a,b) R (c,d) iff a=c or b=d. So with your example, (1,2)R(1,3) iff 1=1 or 2=3. so obviously either one or the other or both... OK I get it now. THANK YOU!!